# How do I redesign my portfolio projects?

Tags: portfolio, redesign, case-studies

So I've recently compiled 3 UX case studies done in classroom on my portfolio website and when asked to present a case study during interview I showcase one case study in the form of presentation slides. But the issue is that the interviewers somehow don't like the process that I have utilised as I think it seems very linear: Secondary research, primary research, contextual inquiry, surveys, competitor analysis, SWOT analysis, ideation, solution sketching, etc. I hope you get how linear this process is.

So I've created the project with it's UI design and have tested with the users. But still somehow it feels like I chose the wrong audience for giving the solution.

So do I start the project again from scratch or now that I have made the UI for a particular audience, I improve it for them?

(Please suggest some tips on improving the UX process as well)

Also I did these projects within a timeline of a month. So how do I optimise to take much lesser time than that for redesign?

Comment: Hi Lavnya. This is a very broad question and we usually answer questions that are more specific and solvable. Could you edit this to show us a specific case study you presented with the negative feedback that you received about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more important to tell the story of the project than to walk through the stages of the project step by step. My suggestion is try to break the story down into a [STAR format](https://www.vawizard.org/wiz-pdf/STAR_Method_Interviews.pdf).

> THE STAR METHOD
>
> ...a structured manner of responding to a behavioral-based interview
> question by discussing the specific situation, task, action, and
> result of the situation you are describing.

Emphasize what the main challenge was of the project, how you overcame that, and what your key learnings as a designer are.

It is a fairly common problem to choose an incorrect audience and this is an opportunity to show what you learned from that and how you corrected the issue. In this case you would want to screen participants you recruit to make sure they fit into your target demographic. You would also want to test the screener to make sure it is screening through the correct people.

You could run a few usability tests with the target demographic and get their input on who they think the product is for and whether or not it works for them. If it doesn't work for them, figure out why and correct it. All projects have hurdles, if you can show that you were able to overcome them you will have a stronger portfolio.

Comment: Do you have a link to an elaboration of the "STAR format" you mention?

Comment: Here's a link to a PDF that describes the STAR format in better detail: https://www.vawizard.org/wiz-pdf/STAR_Method_Interviews.pdf